# Slide right effect with pure CSS

Tags: css, animation, slide

I need to make certain element (with position: fixed) slide from the right side of the screen, stay there for a while and hide from right again. I don't know the width, which makes it harder to achieve. I did it with jQuery before, but I'd like to use pure CSS. Is that possible? I don't mind using third party solution.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$("element")
    .css("right", -$("element").outerWidth() + "px")
    .animate({right: 0}, 800)
    .delay(3000)
    .animate({right: -$("element").outerWidth() + "px"}, 800);
```

Comment: This doesn't mean anything without any HTML. And you don't know the width of what? Animations can be done with CSS, but how do you plan on triggering it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could define `@keyframes` and use percentage values for the `transform` property if the `width` is unknown.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: plum;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-animation: anim 3.5s 1;
  animation: anim 3.5s 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  14.28% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  85.71% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  14.28% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  85.71% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Pretty cool effect, but using CSS for animation always feels clunky.

Comment: @slime You better get using to that clunkiness, it's here to stay

Comment: @JuanMendes For some people sure, but using % to figure out time intervals is annoyingly stupid and needs to be reworked and I won't support it until something better is in place.

Comment: @slime - The tiltle says **pure CSS**, Period! Btw, its not some hardcore math. Simply `100% / 7 = 14.28%` and `100% - 14.28% = 85.71%`.

Comment: It works pretty nice, but there's one problem. Right -100% is actually window's width distance from the edge, not element's edge. That produces a delay before element gets into place. Can it be moved by element's width instead?

Comment: @RoboRobok - Yes, you could use the `transform` property. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I needed to add right and top properties, but other than that it works perfectly! :)